# Pass 'this' as an argument to event handler using on() jQuery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, event-handling, jquery-events

I dynamically add elements with class `.footprint` to DOM and need to add `click()` event to them. My current code looks like this:

```
$("#pcb").on("click", ".footprint", selectFootprint);
```

However, `selectFootprint(sender)` method has a parameter where I would like to pass DOM element (this). 
How can I do it?

Comment: `var sender = this` ?! No need to pass it as a param. Closuring works as well

Comment: @JonasW. That solves my problem, I even didn't think about it. Thanks!

Comment: Are we talking about the context the code is in or are we talking about the `.footprint` element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few solutions (to pass the parents context):

1) using jquerys data parameter:

```
$("#pcb").on("click", ".footprint", this, function(e){
  console.log(this, e.data);//data is the parents this
});
```

2) using a closure

```
var sender = this;
$("#pcb").on("click", ".footprint", function(){
  selectFootprint.call(this, sender);
 });
```

Or if you just want to pass the `.footprint` :

```
$("#pcb").on("click", ".footprint",function(){
 selectFootprint(this);
});
```

Comment: I like the first option, can you provide a solution using my example? Not an anonymous function.

Comment: @vitalii makes no difference

Comment: I do see the difference as in your example you pass the anonymous function and define parameter `e`. But if I use parentheses using my function `selectFootprint` it will be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Acutely,  in [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) jQuery function- `this` keyword is represent the clicked element, so you can call the function as you wished.

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

(From the decomention).

Or in youre case:

```
function selectFootprint(){
   console.log( $( this ).text() );
}
$("#pcb").on("click", ".footprint", selectFootprint);
```

Comment: But here you use an anonymous function. In my case I have a function (event handler) that I'd like to invoke.

Comment: @VitaliiIsaenko it's the same, but i edited my answer to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using selectFootprint directly as a callback, define a new function that calls selectFootprint with this as parameter (this inside an eventlistener always refers to the DOM element the listener is attached to)

```
$(".footprint").on("click", function() {
  selectFootprint(this);
});
```